# Why Chrome has Mozilla in its user agent?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, safari, user-agent

I'm new to headers and user-agent stuff. I'm using a request lib with python to make  a POST operation to a website. I have noticed that the user agent for Chrome is like ***"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"*** as can be checked [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?name=Chrome).

It doesn't only contain "Mozilla" but also "Safari". Why is that and what does it mean?

Comment: *Everyone* has Mozilla.

Comment: I don't get it. Do you mean that Mozilla is the core for each browser? Please clarify.

Comment: From [Why do all browsers' user agents start with “Mozilla/”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114254/why-do-all-browsers-user-agents-start-with-mozilla): It's a [long and sad story](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/).